# How to disable auto inline type comments/hints in Visual Studio Code for F#?

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, ionide

How to get rid of obtrusive auto hints like `// Printf.TextWriterFormat...` generated by VS Code:

[image]

I'm using Ionide plugin with the following `settings.json`:

```
{
  "FSharp.inlayHints.enabled": false,
  "FSharp.inlayHints.disableLongTooltip": true,
  "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "offUnlessPressed",
  "FSharp.inlayHints.typeAnnotations": false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the following:

```
{
  "FSharp.lineLens.enabled": "never"
}
```

You may need to reload the window for it to take effect.

If you also don't want the same information *above* the function definition, you also need

```
{
    "FSharp.codeLenses.signature.enabled": false
}
```

Code lenses are shown above the relevant code; line lenses are shown in-line.